# iOS Devices with Tap to Focus

Tags: ios, camera, hardware

I am working on a project that requires tap to focus for back-facing cameras. I wanted to compile a list of devices that my app is compatible with. Is there a list somewhere on the web that shows all of the iOS devices that support tap to focus? Here is what I know so far:

Supports Tap to Focus:

iPhone 5: YES

iPhone 4: YES

iPhone 3Gs: YES

iPod Touch 5th Gen: YES

Everything else: NO

Are there any other devices I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a completed list of devices that have autofocus/tap to focus functionality:

iPhone 3gs, 4, 4s, 5
iPod touch 5th generation
iPad 3 gen and beyond

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any other devices I am missing?

Recent iPad models have rear cameras that support tap to focus. The "new" iPad introduced in April (or thereabout) has it, as does the even newer version with the Lightning connector. I don't have an iPad mini to check, but I'd be surprised if it doesn't have the same camera.

**Update:** The iPad mini does indeed support tap to focus according to [the specs](http://www.apple.com/ipad-mini/specs/).